# Testing multiple login controller to multiple sites

Tags: unit-test, community, login

I have two communities with custom login controllers which I want to test.

I am attempting to execute login as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AzuJIAS), but site.login just returns null. Is there a missing piece, like how do you specify which actual portal/site/community you are logging into?

**edit**: I am not using `seeAllData` flag though. Is that mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

**[Site class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm)** method always return null if they are not called or run inside Site. This is a standard Salesforce limitation so unfortunately you cannot do much in this case. But you can use

`Test.isRunningTest()` 
with the help of this you can cover your test class.